# PasswordRecovery Issues 

Tags: asp.net, sql, security

building an application and I have had some trouble with the PasswordRecovery utility. I am using the ASP.NET built in Configuration Tool. My issue is that I cannot use the provided PasswordRecovery control because I do not have an SMTP server setup and don't know how to do so.

I have tried to customize the control to allow me to display the users password inside a label after a succesful password recovery. Here is my code so far:

```
protected void PasswordRecovery1_SendingMail(object sender, MailMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        MembershipUser user;
        user = Membership.GetUser(PasswordRecovery1.UserName);
        label1.Text = user.GetPassword();


    }
```

here is the error I recieve:

```
This Membership Provider has not been configured to support password retrieval.
```

now I did some research on this error and came across something odd. The ASP.NET tool did not add any type of Membership Provider to my web.config file. Also when I try to test the database through the configuration tool here is what I get:

```
Could not establish a connection to the database. 
If you have not yet created the SQL Server database, exit the Web Site Administration tool, use the aspnet_regsql command-line utility to create and configure the database, and then return to this tool to set the provider.
```

Can anybody help me to access the user's password after a successful password recovery? If it is easy to get the SMTP going I may attempt that, but I think it would be easier to just show the users password on the label?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Password recovery is **bad idea** anyway. You want to provide a _reset mechanism_ rather than full recovery, as you should not store passwords in a way that is reversible in the first place.

Comment: I agree. either way ok... but I can't set the  enablePasswordReset="true" because it throws an error with my current configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the error on resetting the password is the way to go. Why don't you ask for help with that instead?

Just get an SMTP server set up - there is one included with IIS you just have to install it.

**Don't** do password recovery, it's a **bad idea**. Also you should't be storing passwords in the clear. Ever. ***Ever ever.***

Comment: So would this SMTP server need to be installed on every machine that will be running my application? or just the main server?

Comment: @shenn, the application needs access to an SMTP server. Where you put it or whether you use an existing one in your organisation is up to you. Putting one on each webserver will help with network outages but will also be an extra thing which needs to be secured.

Comment: @shenn, ask on serverfault.com to find out how to set up SMTP servers